# How to make a ListView move horizontally right or left when I am scrolling down

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, scroll

My question is:

How can I make a ListView that contains Categories move horizontally right or left depending on which Category I reach when I am scrolling down.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a combination of https://pub.dev/packages/inview_notifier_list to check which section is in view and https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index to scroll the first listview accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 
In my project, what solved my problem is "ItemPositionsListener".

Answer (score 0):

Just add this attribute to the

```
ListView.builder(
scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
)
```